# Why does $watch trigger with AngularJS when nothing has changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone explain why $watch() is firing for my scope, even though newValue == oldValue here?

```
scope.$watch('element', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue == oldValue) {
        console.log(newValue == oldValue);
        return;
    }
}, true);
```

"true" is output, and newValue and oldValue are both objects having the same values:

```
{"formID":"536826128a1c00617d3e4c5f","elementType":"TextFieldElement","required":false,"note":"","label":"","fieldName":"","_id":"5368261b8a1c00617d3e4c60","__v":0,"$$hashKey":"01B"}
{"formID":"536826128a1c00617d3e4c5f","elementType":"TextFieldElement","required":false,"note":"","label":"","fieldName":"","_id":"5368261b8a1c00617d3e4c60","__v":0,"$$hashKey":"01B"}
```

I understand from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) that passing "true" for the third parameter to $watch compares for object equality using angular.equals(). I also tested with angular.equals(), and it also returns true. So why is $watch() being triggered at all?

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.16.

Comment: Is it only once? That does happen on init and the docs say to check for it by comparing oldVal and newVal.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to only happen on init, and that appears to have been the problem. I overlooked that in the docs. Using a === check in the listener solves the problem. If you'd like to post an answer here, I'll be happy to mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the angular docs, this can happen on initialization:

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.